# Parse a php file and store result into a variable

Tags: php, parsing, html-email

I'm currently writing my HTML email code and run into the following problem:

When defining the content of the email (`$message`), I would like to parse a php file that has a few php code and a lot of html, and store the result in that specific variable (`$message`).

I tried with `file_get_contents()`, but this does basically the opposite of what I want, because it doesn't parse the PHP, only the HTML.

Which function suits my needs or what workaround id needed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use this,

```
ob_start();
include "yourfile.php";
$myvar = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: +1, but remember to indent your code so it shows up as code ;)

Comment: Many thanks for the reply! It worked just perfectly! I thought that it won't work because the ob_start() isn't at the beginning of the file, but it works. However I guess if anything would have been outputted before the ob_start() it wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: Can this function `ob_start` be used multiple times on one single php file?